# Int variables NOT being updated in a recurring input?

Tags: java, recursion, methods, numbers, logic

```
Link to specific problem: https://hyperskill.org/projects/48/stages/258/implement#comment

public class Main {    

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    public static void edit(char[][] matrix){
        System.out.print("Enter the coordinates: ");
        String coords = input.nextLine();

        String coords2 = coords.replaceAll("\\s", "");

        int coordsNum = Integer.parseInt(coords2);
        int compare = coordsNum % 10;
        int compare2 = coordsNum / 10;

        for(int i = 0; i < coords2.length(); i++){

            if(compare < 1 || compare > 3 || compare2 < 1 || compare2 > 3){
                //Code
                edit(matrix);
            }
            //Check if input are numbers
            if(!Character.isDigit(coords2.charAt(i))){
                //Code
                edit(matrix);
            }
        }
```

}

When I the recursion occurs, and I type a new String, the variables coordsNum, compare, and compare2 are not updated from my input. They remain the same whenever my input is below 0 or above 3. I tried making the variables into one single input line but that did not work. There is nothing wrong with the logic either.

Ex) Input: 4 1 -> Recur -> 1 3 -> Print out values, prints 4,1 instead of 1,3

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Yup! It is supposed to take in a new input and with that new input updates the variables.

Comment: Please then clarify your question. It's not clear.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri What part seems confusing? Every time the recursion call is made, the variables coordsNum, compare, and compare2 are supposed to be updated to that input, yet when I print them out, they aren't the latest input.

Comment: What is the data you're feeding in? what you mean - they are supposed to be updated? in this code, you should provide an input for every recursive call.

Comment: Provide a specific input you're trying to give it.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I am inputing a String. For example, `"4 1"` is taken in, the replaceAll method converts it to `"41"`. The coordsNum variable converts the String to an int so it can be compared in the logic that follows. `compare = 1` and `compare2 = 4`. So when the recursion call is made, those variables are not updated to a new input.

Answer (score 0):

This code is quite strange.

So lets look at what happens:

1. `edit#1` prints `"Enter the coordinates: "`
2. You read `"4 2"` as a whole line into the variable `coords`.
3. You create `coords2` to `"42"` by removing whitespace from `coords`.
4. you create `cordsnum = 42` and `compare = 2` and `compare2 = 4`
5. You start a `for` loop of 2 iterations (edit#1for#1)
6. in `edit#1for` `i = 0` you check bounds for `compare` and `compare2` where `compare2 > 3`
7. `edit#2` prints `"Enter the coordinates: "`
8. You read `"2 2"` as a whole line into variables `coords`.
9. You create `coords2` to `"22"` by removing whitespace from `coords`.
10. you create `cordsnum = 22` and `compare = 2` and `compare2 = 2`
11. You start a `for` loop of 2 iterations (edit#2for)
12. in `edit#2for` `i = 0` you check bounds for `compare` and `compare2` where non matches
13. you check if `!Character.isDigit("22".charAt(0))`, which is `false`
14. in `edit#2for` `i = 1` you check bounds AGAIN for `compare` and `compare2` where non matches
15. you check if `!Character.isDigit("22".charAt(1))`, which is `false`
16. method returns to `edit#1`, here `coord2` is `"42"`, `coordnum=42`, `compare = 2`, and `compare2 = 4`
17. you check `!Character.isDigit("42".charAt(0))`, which is `false`
18. in `edit#1for` `i = 1` you check AGAIN bounds for `compare` and `compare2` where `compare2 > 3`
19. `edit#3` prints `"Enter the coordinates: "`
20. ...

So what I'm not sure why you check if `compare2` contains numbers since if it didn't Integer.parseInt(coords2) would throw an exception and you never get to check it. Also checking `compare < 1 || compare > 3 || compare2 < 1 || compare2 > 3` twice is the reason why you end up doing another round even when you inputed ok data.

What I want to to understand is that when a method returns it resumes from the callee. It does not care if it called itself since it is a different version of itself with their own variables. When it returns it returns one step and continues just as you would assume with a non recursive call. No difference there at all.

Good luck with your challenge!